# Segemented Control for iPhone not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a segmented control with the following code in its action method:

```
-(IBAction)toggleControls:(id)sender{
    if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == kSwitchesSegmentIndex){
        leftSwitch.hidden = NO;
        rightSwitch.hidden = NO;
        doSomethingButton.hidden = YES;
    }

    else{
        leftSwitch.hidden = YES;
        rightSwitch.hidden = YES;
        doSomethingButton.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

However, when I run the program I'm getting an error with `kSwitchesSegmentIndex`. It's saying that `kSwitchesSegmentIndex` is an undeclared identifier. Can anyone help me with what's wrong here?

Comment: What is kSwitchSegmentIndex? Where do you define/declare it?

Comment: what is this kSwitchesSegmentIndex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show us where `kSwitchesSegmentIndex` is being defined.  The convention is to define variables like that like:

```
#define kSwitchesSegmentIndex 1
```

Or, you could define it as an int:

```
int kSwitchesSegmentIndex = 1;
```

Since it shouldn't need to change value the first choice might be best.

Example:

```
#include <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

#define kMyConstant1 0
#define kMyConstant2 1

@implementation MyClass
```

Comment: what does #define mean and where would I put it?

Comment: It's a direction for the processor -- tells it to assign a value to that term.  Like a variable, but it has a constant value (thus the k prefix commonly used, I believe).  Putting it before your @implementation statement in a .m file, is the most common.  See updated answer for an example.  In this case, you'll want to set the values based on which switch you're testing for

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared the `kSwitchesSegmentIndex` in your code ,

Do Something

```
#define kSwitchesSegmentIndex 0
```

Comment: Where would I need to put this code? Also what does #define mean?

Comment: Put it in the same file where you  like to use it ,

Answer (score 1):

You need to define that undefined symbol with some value.

The variable that you have used `kSwitchesSegmentIndex` is not declared anywhere in your code.

So just declare your constant with value like this:

```
#define kSwitchesSegmentIndex 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done mistakes in declaration of `kSwitchesSegmentIndex`.